# strange behavior of an OpenMP program

Tags: openmp

I'm debugging an OpenMP program. Its behavior is strange.

1) If a simple program P (while(1) loop) occupies one core 100%, the OpenMP program pauses even it occupies all remained cores. Once I terminate the program P, OpenMP program continues to execute.

2) The OpenMP program can execute successfully in situation 1 if I set OMP_NUMBER_THREADS to 32/16/8.

I tested on both 8-core x64 machines and 32-core Itanium machines. The former uses GCC and libomp. The later uses privately-owned aCC compiler and libraries. So it is unlikely related to compiler/library.

Could you help point out any possible reasons which may cause the scene? Why can it be affected by another program?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that you need to give more information.

- What is the OS you are running on?
- When you run using 16 threads are you doing this on the 8-core or the 32 core machine?
- What is the simple while(p) program doing in this while loop?
- What is the OpenMP program doing (in general terms - if you can't be specific)?
- Have you tried using a profiling tool to see what the OpenMP program is doing?